# Does node-sparql-client handle communication with endpoint synchronously?

Tags: node.js, sparql

I am using [node-sparql-client](https://github.com/thomasfr/node-sparql-client)  to query my endpoint and retrieve SPARQL results. Is this communication with endpoint and execution of the function/callback (after the query results are obtained) handled synchronously? I looked at [client.js](https://github.com/thomasfr/node-sparql-client/blob/master/lib/client.js), but could not figure out much.

Comment: That there are a bunch of `continuation`s and `callback`s in that code suggests that there's some asynchronous execution.

Comment: Thanks!. I need to send 6 queries to the endpoint sequentially. So, I need to put call to sparql-client in some synchronous block.

Answer (score 0):

The example usage from the project shows a call to the `execute` function:

```
client.query(query)
  //.bind('city', 'db:Chicago')
  //.bind('city', 'db:Tokyo')
  //.bind('city', 'db:Casablanca')
  .bind('city', '<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Vienna>')
  .execute(function(error, results) { … });              ; ** callback here
```

The `execute` function is defined in `client.js`:

```
SparqlClient.prototype.execute = function (callback) {
  this.sparqlRequest(this.currentQuery, callback);
  return this;
}
```

The query is made asynchronously, and it's the `callback` that actually processes the results.  If you need to run a second query after the first one is completed and its results are available, just put it inside the callback.

Comment: Thank you, but I have 6 queries, not just 2. I have stored the queries in an array and am looping through it. For each query, I send it to the endpoint using sparql-client and when the callback returns, process the results of that query. Then go on for the next query.

Comment: The same principle applies;  just have the callback have an index into the array, and increment the index for the next callback, until there are no more queries to process…

Comment: I'm not much of a Javascript-er, but here's an example of using callbacks to perform iteration in Common Lisp.  The idea is to have your callback function reference an index and to call query again with the incremented index.  http://pastebin.com/HruAhcmb